# How can I Update data in b-modal Vue/watch a change in array length and update?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, modal-dialog, bootstrap-vue

I have a table with list of products. On clicking the edit button on each row, b-modal used from bootstrap-vue pops up with the array of images displayed:
This is my b-modal:

```
<b-modal size="xl" scrollable 
  id="productModal"
  ref="productModal"
  v-bind:title="this.editMode ? 'Update Product' : 'Add new Product'"
>

  <form ref="productForm" @submit.stop.prevent="handleSubmit">
    <v-app>
      <v-container fluid >
          <v-row dense>
            <v-col
              v-for="(item,index) in this.existingImage"
              :key="item.id"
              :cols="item.flex"
            >
              <v-card>
                
                <v-img
                  :src="item.url"
                  class="white--text align-end"
                  gradient="to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,.1), rgba(0,0,0,.5)"
                  height="200px"
                >
                  <v-card-title v-text="item.id">aas</v-card-title>
                </v-img>
                
    
                <v-card-actions>
                  <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                  <v-btn icon @click="deleteExistingImage(index,form.id,item.id)">
                    <v-icon>mdi-delete</v-icon>
                  </v-btn>
                </v-card-actions>
              </v-card>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-container>

        <v-file-input multiple chips required
        v-model="image" accept="image/*" @change="onFileChange" 
        label="File input" :error-messages="imageErrors"
        @input="$v.image.$touch()"
            @blur="$v.image.$touch()"></v-file-input>

        
     
    </v-container>
    </v-app>
  </form>
  <template v-slot:modal-footer>
        <div class="w-100">
            <b-button :disabled="loading"
            variant="primary"
            size="sm"
            class="forHover float-right"
            @click.prevent="submitForm(editMode)"
        >
                <div class="lds-ring-container" v-if="loading">
                    <div class="lds-ring"><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
                </div>
                    Save
                
            </b-button>

            
        </div>
    </template>
</b-modal>
```

loadData() to fetch all data from db:

```
data() {
return {
    existingImage:[],
    editMode: false,
    date: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),
    menu2: false,
    loading:false, 
    allData:[]
};
```

},

```
loadData() {
      ProductDataService.getAll()
        .then(response => {
          this.isloading = false;
          this.allData= response.data[0].data;
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    },
```

This is my code in Vue to pass data in editForm:

```
editModal(row){
    this.editMode = true;
    this.existingImage = row.image;
    this.form.id = row.id;
    this.$bvModal.show('productModal');
    this.form.fill(row);
},


<v-container fluid >
          <v-row dense>
            <v-col
              v-for="(item,index) in this.existingImage"
              :key="item.id"
              :cols="item.flex"
            >
              <v-card>
                
                <v-img
                  :src="item.url"
                  class="white--text align-end"
                  gradient="to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,.1), rgba(0,0,0,.5)"
                  height="200px"
                >
                  <v-card-title v-text="item.id">aas</v-card-title>
                </v-img>
                
    
                <v-card-actions>
                  <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                  <v-btn icon @click="deleteExistingImage(index,form.id,item.id)">
                    <v-icon>mdi-delete</v-icon>
                  </v-btn>
                </v-card-actions>
              </v-card>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-container>
```

On deleting the image api is called as below which works perfectly fine :

```
ProductDataService.deleteImage(productId, imageId)
            .then(response => {
                this.loadData();
                this.$toasted.success('Product Image deleted!', {
                    action: {
                        onClick: (e, toastObject) => {
                            toastObject.goAway(0);
                        }
                    }
                })
            })
```

After the image gets deleted loadData() function gets all the updated records from db. But in the modal the image is still there. After closing the modal and re-opening it only then the image deleted is not shown. How can I update the data in b-modal as soon as the image gets deleted? Or how can I watch existingImages value change and update in my b-modal?

Comment: Can you show how you mutate `this.existingImage`. Please add the loadData function and the corresponding data keys

Comment: Where is `<b-modal>`?

Comment: @Hiws   I have updated my code

Comment: @Sølve Tornøe updated my code